# Regex left join in KDB

Tags: kdb

In KDB, is it possible to perform a lj (Left-Join) using "like" or "~" to join 2 tables where 1 table's key matches another tables's key by regex?

Comment: Hi delita, would you be able to give an example of the tables you are working with and what the desired output should look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not using out-of-the-box tools, but you could do something like this (won't be incredibly efficient)

```
q)t:([]sym:`ACF`ABC`ABD`BA`AAF`AABG`CDE;col1:til 7)

q)t2:([]regex:("*AB*";"AA?";"A*";"C*");col2:4#.Q.A)

q)t,'t2 first each where each t[`sym]like'\:t2[`regex]
sym  col1 regex  col2
---------------------
ACF  0    "A*"   C
ABC  1    "*AB*" A
ABD  2    "*AB*" A
BA   3    ""
AAF  4    "AA?"  B
AABG 5    "*AB*" A
CDE  6    "C*"   D
```

This approach would take the first matched pattern if there's more than one match.

Another idea is to create a manufactured key and left join on the manufactured key.